# WPF binding Listbox layoutpanel

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, devexpress

I´m using devexpress and I want to do a binding with a Listbox, but I have an error. Here my code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="_list" >                            
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <dxd:LayoutPanel 
                Caption="{Binding nameList}"
                AllowHide ="False" AllowFloat="False"                                            
                GotFocus="panel_GotFocus" >

                <TextBox Text="Hello" />

             </dxd:LayoutPanel>                                   

         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                            
 </ListBox>
```

With this code, Caption {Binding nameList} is empty.

I have tried this.

```
<ListBox x:Name="_list" >                            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                     <TextBox Text="{Binding nameList}" />
                 </Grid>                                                                      
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                            
     </ListBox>
```

In this case, text in TextBox is correct, I need to use the first code.

Comment: You should at least mention you're using DevExpress here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit confused about how to use this `ListBox`. First, you need a collection property to bind to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property. Let's say you have a collection of `User` objects called `Users`:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Users}" />
```

Now we want to define how each `User` should be displayed... all the properties of the `User` class will be available to the `Binding` inside the `DataTemplate`. Let's say that the `User` class has two properties; `Name` and `Age`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourDataTypeNamespace:User}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then putting it all together:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourDataTypeNamespace:User}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                            
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: I´ve tried it but it is not working, I think that the problem is layoutPanel because is a devexpress object and the functioning is diferent. If I use <StackPanel> or other native object it is working.